# setup lldb debugging with cpp extension in vscode linux

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I mostly use gdb for debugging c++ single files in vscode but now want to try lldb but i am facing issues while setting it up for vscode.

I first create default launch.json form debug tab selecting `cpp gdb/lldb` then `clang++` for configuration.

When the debugging starts.. it shows following error:

[image: When the debugging starts.. it shows following error:]

then in launch.json I changed `miDebuggerPath` path form  `/usr/bin/lldb-mi` to `/usr/bin/lldb`.

Then when I launch the debugger it does NOTHING just debug controls up top and following lines in terminal:

```
warning: ignoring unknown option: --interpreter=mi
warning: ignoring unknown option: --tty=/dev/pts/1
```

anything I am missing here?

My whole `launch.json` is:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "clang++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang++ build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/lldb"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: for reference, some related questions: [debugging with lldb clang does not work on WSL with VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71083482/6338809), [How to debug in VS Code using lldb?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70245851/6338809)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`lldb-mi` is not part of the LLDB project. see [lists.llvm.org](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/lldb-dev/2019-August/015357.html)

you can still build it yourself from the project's [github repo](https://github.com/lldb-tools/lldb-mi). you will need to build LLDB/Clang/LLVM first, since `lldb-mi`compilation requires headers and compiled libraries for the build to work as per information stated in the README.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69095402/6338809), and discussed [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5415), using `lldb-mi` may not be the best option.

`lldb-vscode` (https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/lldb/tools/lldb-vscode) works well to enable debugging with lldb in vscode on linux, and is part of the LLDB project.  Here are the steps I used (taken from the readme) to set it up on a remote-ssh vscode server (assumes llvm installation exists):

1. Create the vscode extension

   ```bash
   # Create directory for a new VSCode extension
   $ mkdir -p  ~/.vscode-server/extensions/llvm-org.lldb-vscode-0.1.0/bin
   # Copy the extension package.json from GitHub
   $ wget -P ~/.vscode-server/extensions/llvm-org.lldb-vscode-0.1.0/ 
   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/llvm/llvm-project/main/lldb/tools/lldb-vscode/package.json
   # Copy the lldb-vscode binary to the bin directory
   $ cp $(which lldb-vscode) ~/.vscode-server/extensions/llvm-org.lldb-vscode-0.1.0/bin/
   # Copy the lldb-server binary to the bin directory
   $ cp $(which lldb-server) ~/.vscode-server/extensions/llvm-org.lldb-vscode-0.1.0/bin/
   # also make sure all libraries are found by ldd for the copied binaries,
   # e.g. liblldb.so.13
   ```

   Now under the extensions tab in vscode on my remote host, "LLDB native Debug stub" is shown
2. Create a launch.json, for example

   ```json
   {
       "version": "0.2.0",
       "configurations": [
           {
               "name": "Launch lldb-vscode",
               "type": "lldb-vscode",
               "request": "launch",
               "program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
               "args": [],
               "env": [],
               "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
               "stopOnEntry": false,
               "sourceMap": [["/path/a/", "/path/b"]]
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

---

Notes for Ubuntu:

In a Ubuntu distro, llvm can be installed from the package manager, e.g. `apt install lldb-13`. In this case, `lldb-server` and `lldb-vscode` are not on the path so the commands above will not work. Taking a look at the installed package:

```bash
$ dpkg --search lldb-vscode
lldb-13: /usr/bin/lldb-vscode-13
lldb-13: /usr/lib/llvm-13/bin/lldb-vscode
$ ls -l /usr/bin/lldb-vscode-13
/usr/bin/lldb-vscode-13 -> ../lib/llvm-13/bin/lldb-vscode

$ dpkg --search lldb-server
lldb-13: /usr/lib/llvm-13/bin/lldb-server
lldb-13: /usr/lib/llvm-13/bin/lldb-server-13
lldb-13: /usr/bin/lldb-server-13
lldb-13: /usr/lib/llvm-13/bin/lldb-server-13.0.0
$ ls -l /usr/bin/lldb-server-13
/usr/bin/lldb-server-13 -> ../lib/llvm-13/bin/lldb-server
$ ls -l /usr/lib/llvm-13/bin/lldb-server*
/usr/lib/llvm-13/bin/lldb-server
/usr/lib/llvm-13/bin/lldb-server-13 -> lldb-server
/usr/lib/llvm-13/bin/lldb-server-13.0.0 -> lldb-server
```

Therefore, for Ubuntu, for example, `cd ~/.vscode-server/extensions/llvm-org.lldb-vscode-0.1.0/bin` and do:

```bash
$ cp /usr/lib/llvm-13/bin/lldb-vscode .
$ cp /usr/lib/llvm-13/bin/lldb-server .
# make the same symlinks as in the package
$ ln -s lldb-server lldb-server-13
$ ln -s lldb-server lldb-server-13.0.0
```

Comment: I got `unable to locate lldb-server-14.0.0` error, and it suggests to `Open 'launch.json'`. What option do I need to add? ps. I've added symlink to `lldb-server-14` with the name `lldb-server-14.0.0`, no effect.

Comment: @amordo try `$ cp $(which lldb-server) ~/.vscode-server/extensions/llvm-org.lldb-vscode-0.1.0/bin/`. If that works I'll edit the answer to add that

Comment: stranger things, it works in the extension bin directory if the name exactly matches the name in error. So in my case I have `~/.vscode-server/extensions/llvm-org.lldb-vscode-0.1.0/bin/lldb-server-14.0.0`, not `lldb-server`, nor `lldb-server-14`. ty!

Comment: Heads up to anyone reading this, `lldb-vscode` has been renamed to `lldb-dap`.

Answer (score 3):

[CodeLLDB](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb) extension works perfectly in Ubuntu docker container launched in Windows 10. It suggests some predefined configs.
I had troubles with `gdb` that threw out core-dump on multithreaded application; `lldb-vscode` also required some efforts as discussed in comments of [Joe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72386036/9007136).
PS: Container has `gcc` `clang` `lldb` installed by `apt`, maybe they are necessary for the plugin to work (maybe not)
[image]