# debugging with lldb clang does not work on WSL with VSCode

Tags: c, linux, debugging, visual-studio-code, clang

I am using clang 13 for compiling and lldb 13 for debugging on WSL (kali linux) using Visual Studio Code.

I found that the mi debugger - `lldb-mi` - isn't available on apt-get, so I had to compile it from source. I looked into issue [#5415](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5415) on VS Code cpptools and the answer suggested [there](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5415#issuecomment-662603085) to download the latest `clang`, `lldb` versions and compile `lldb-mi` from source.

After following all the steps, `lldb-mi` still does not work in VSCode. As a result I have gone back to using `gdb` as the debugger with `clang` still for building.

However, I don't understand the problem here. I compiled and linked everything without errors but when run, the debugger simply outputs nothing, even with simplest hello world example. Why is this happening?

*Details:*

Here is the script I used to compile `lldb-mi` with its dependencies:

```sh
sudo apt install clang-13 llvm-13-dev liblldb-13-dev
sudo ln -f -s /usr/bin/clang-13 /usr/bin/clang
sudo ln -f -s /usr/bin/clang++-13 /usr/bin/clang++
sudo ln -f -s /usr/bin/lldb-13 /usr/bin/lldb
sudo ln -f -s /usr/bin/lldb-server-13 /usr/bin/lldb-server-13.0.0
sudo ln -f -s /usr/bin/lldb-server-13 /usr/bin/lldb-server-13.0.1
git clone https://github.com/lldb-tools/lldb-mi.git
cd lldb-mi
rm ./src/lldb-mi
cmake .
cmake --build .
sudo cp src/lldb-mi /usr/bin/
```

Here is my `launch.json`:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "clang + lldb Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: clang build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/lldb-mi"
        }
    ]
}
```